# Displaying in table format

Tags: php, foreach, html-table

I am new to the programming - I am retrieving information from database and I have to display these items 3 per row.
Here is the code:

```
<?php 
if($top) { 
   foreach($top as $val)
   { 
?>       
<tr>
<?php for($c=0;$c<=3;$c++) { ?>
   <td>
       <img src="<?= $val['image']; ?>" style="width: 75px;height: 75px;"/>
   </td>
<?php } ?>
</tr>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

but this shows same item 3 times in a row.

Comment: What is the content of $top variable?

Comment: You are not using $c to go thru items in $val row. PHP can't figure out

Comment: $top contains names of some images in database

Comment: Can you show the output of print_r($top);?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is actually tabular data I would display all the items in a list (`ul`) and then simply display all the `li`s as `inline-block` and give them 33% width:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="my-list-of-items">
    <?php foreach ($top as $val) : ?>
        <li><img src="<?php echo $val['image'] ?>" alt="" width="75" height="75"/>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#my-list-of-items {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

    #my-list-of-items li {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33%;
    }
```

Edit: If you *have* to use a table, what you want to do is print a `</tr><tr>` every third item. You can use modulus for this:

```
if ($i++ % 3 == 0) echo '</tr><tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what you want to achieve. From your print_r $val['image'] will not return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why there is the for loop, and the image isn't in `$val['image']` but in `$val['preacher_image']` or in `$val['sermon_image']`.

Your script should look like:

```
<?php 
if($top) { 
    $i = 0;
    foreach($top as $val) { 
        if ($i%3 == 0) echo "<tr>";
?>       
   <td>
       <img src="<?= $val['preacher_image']; ?>" style="width: 75px;height: 75px;"/>
   </td>
<?php
        if ($i%3 == 0) echo "</tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    if ($i%3 != 1) echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```